# Getting HPE_INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR when sending a get request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

This code was working flawlessly yesterday/earlier today, now it responds with empty response and body and a `HPE_INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR` in the error on the request callback. I really don't know what to do.

```
this.getVerifyAge = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let url = 'https://example.org/api/';
        //let url = 'https://www.google.ca'
        let headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'club.pokemon.com',
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'
        };
        var options = {
            url: url,
            //headers: headers,
            jar: this.j
        }
        if (this.proxy) {
            options.proxy = this.proxy;
        }
        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error || response.statusCode === 502) {
                reject(new Error('ERROR : getVerifyAge'));
            }
            else {

            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I just wanna add that it works 100% of the time when I send a get with no headers with postman

Comment: I also tried the http-parser-js method with no success